# How to remove parent from master branch in git?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have 2 branches in our bitbucket cloud app.
`Master`
`Dev`
Master is truly my master branch with no parent
Dev's parent is Master
These 2 branches deviated over many years to the point where I could not merge *Dev* back into *Master* without thousands of conflicts. The code in Master is very old and I just wanted to replace it with the latest from the *Dev* branch, so I followed the following link https://www.nickang.com/2017-09-30-replace-git-branch-code/ to completely replace the code in *Master* with the code in *Dev* and that works but one side effect was discovered after the fact.
When I click on my *Dev* branch its parent is *Master*
But when I click on my *Master* branch, its parent is now *Dev* and that is not right.

[image]
[image]

How can I remove the parent of *Master* or change it to *Master* > *Master*
I tried `git rebase --onto master master` but that did not work

Comment: Branches do not have parent branches. Branches—more precisely, branch *names* (the term *branch* means different things to people)—just name the *last commit* that we say is "on" that branch. Two branch names can point to the same commit; that commit and all its ancestors are on both branches.

Answer (score 1):

Well that's a pretty strange article. It sounds to me like what you wanted to do is far simpler. Delete master and change dev's name to master! Done. So...

Stay on dev and:

```
git branch -d master                   
git branch -m master
```

Done. The only problem now is that you need to tell the remote what you've done. Here's how:

```
git push -u --force origin master
git push --delete origin dev
```

Just to prove that this works, here I am, doing it; my primary branch is called `main` not `master`, but that's unimportant. Before:

```
* 0893bc9 (HEAD -> dev) z
* 2a765b5 y
* 5a36f79 x
| * 620ef05 (main) f
| * 4427352 e
| * 239eaf9 d
|/  
* b1abb03 c
* 48f4d62 b
* 09dc05f a
```

And after:

```
* 0893bc9 (HEAD -> main, origin/main) z
* 2a765b5 y
* 5a36f79 x
* b1abb03 c
* 48f4d62 b
* 09dc05f a
```

I believe that's what you said you wanted. Everything in main after the point where dev diverged from it has been replaced by the contents of dev.

If you want to keep using dev going forward, you can now make a new dev branch and push it.

Comment: thanks Matt, deleting and renaming is what I ended up doing. I would have like to keep history in dev branch but not a big deal, its there in Master branch now.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: See the last sentence of my answer. If you create a new dev branch now, as I said, its history is the same as the old dev.